# Navigate between two stack Navigators after login in react native

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, navigation, runtime-error

This is my first stack

```
<NavigationContainer>
     <Stack.Navigator
       initialRouteName="Home"
       screenOptions={{
         headerShown: false,
       }}
     >
       <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={MainScreen} />
       <Stack.Screen name="Schools" component={SchoolsScreen} />
       <Stack.Screen name="Setting" component={SettingScreen} />
       <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
       <Stack.Screen name="Saved" component={SavedData} />
       <Stack.Screen name="Profile2" component={Profile2} />
       <Stack.Screen name="SchoolDetails" component={SchoolDetailsScreen} />
       <Stack.Screen name="Bottom" component={BottomTab} />
     </Stack.Navigator>
   </NavigationContainer>
```

This is my second stack

```
<NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator
        initialRouteName="Login"
        screenOptions={{
          headerShown: false,
        }}
      >
        <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={AuthLogin} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={AuthRegister} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Forget" component={ForgetPassword} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
```

THis is my **app.js** file

```
  const [auth, setAuth] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem("isLoggedin");
      console.log(value);
      setAuth(value);
    })();
  }, []);
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <NativeBaseProvider config={config}>
        {auth == "true" ? <InsideStack /> : <OutsideStack />}
      </NativeBaseProvider>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

I want to navigate to home screen from login screen , after function call

```
          // navigation.push("Home");
          const storeData = async (value) => {
            try {
              await AsyncStorage.setItem("isLoggedin", JSON.stringify(true));
            } catch (e) {
              // saving error
            }
          };
          storeData();
          navigation.push("Home");
        }}
```

But i got error:

> Do you have a screen named 'Home'?

Comment: Just change `auth` state from `"false"` to `"true"`. Replace `navigation.push("Home");` to `setAuth("true");`.

Comment: Not, it should navigate from from login to home screen, see 4th code

Answer (score 0):

this is the simple code for this. you have to use redux or context api for gloal state management. here is a min example ;

```
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import React from 'react';
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux';
import {GetUserContacts} from '../logic/getcontact';
import {setContacts} from '../store/actions/ContactActions';
import AuthNavigation from './AuthNavigation';
import RootNavigation from './RootNavigation';
const AppContainer = () => {
    const {is_logged_in} = useSelector(state => state.persistedReducer);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    if (is_logged_in) {
        GetUserContacts('PK').then(data => {
            dispatch(setContacts(data));
        });
    }
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            {is_logged_in ? <RootNavigation /> : <AuthNavigation />}
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
};

export default AppContainer;
```

after user logged in you have to make that **`is_logged_in`**  true. so the navigator changes itself. you will have to persist this so when application restart the user dont need to login again

Comment: what is need , is when i click the function ,then the screen should move from <OutsideStack/> to <insideStack/> , or from login screen to Home screen. as i mention above

Comment: you need to create a global store with redux or context where you would toggle with is_logged_in variable from false to true when sign in and from true to false when sign out. it will automatically change your stacks